# CartThrob Lite: Payments button not working in settings. Any Ideas?

Tags: cartthrob

I'm a newbie to SE, not so new to EE :)

I've got CartThrob Lite v2.3.3 Installed on EE 2.6.1 and I'm experiencing a weird issue:

When you go to Cart Throb > Settings and click the Payments button it redirects to the front-end 404 page which is a bit alarming.

Has anyone else had the same issue or can think of a workaround?

as I really need to be able to configure my payment gateways in order to move forward with this project.

If you need any more information- just ask!

Cheers,
Neil